# Identifying my trip-lever drain stopper to buy a replacement

Tags: drain, bathtub

I inherited a rented apartment with a trip-lever drain stopper in the bathtub with the stopper itself missing (see attached images). The maintenance told me that they cannot replace the missing part and gave a generic rubber cover instead, which is both inconvenient and hideous.

Ignoring the fact that this apartment is some 60 years old and the entire thing is in pretty bad condition, what would I need to know to order a replacement myself? Presumably, installing it would be as simple as sticking it in the sinkhole once I have it.

I can see that the lever handle was made by Kohler, but I am unable to find any similar-looking products on their website and their customer support told me that I have to replace the entire bathtub which seems a bit excessive. I am worried about ordering a plug from a different manufacturer as I have no way of knowing if it is going to be compatible (although presumably the only thing that matters is the diameter, but I am not sure).

I was hoping to get some advice on finding a suitable replacement for the missing component that I can buy and install myself without getting Kohler to replace the entire unit.

Unfortunately, I know absolutely nothing about plumbing and have never had an issue like this before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the level mechanism still functional? Does the lever in the drain hole move when you move the handle up above side to side?

Comment: Yes, it is functional!

Comment: Apparently, my assembly is described as "Antique vintage Kohler bath tub drain overflow assembly 1960's" by this [website](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/antique-vintage-kohler-bath-tub-drain-467779097), which is not very reassuring...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adamant about keeping the side-to-side lever on the overflow here are some [choices for a replacement](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=trip-lever%20drain%20stopper&i=tools&qid=1610052343&ref=sr_pg_1).

You may be able to install a simpler drain stop with [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00402VW2E)

finally, if you just want to install the [missing piece](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KKMVHK)

Below are the (2) most commonest drain stopper types which may help you with choosing a replacement or part.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As of the first link, am I to assume that all those choices available on Amazon will fit my tub? I am not sure if there is a single standard or I need to be more careful.
 
The second link does not seem to work :(
 
As of the third link, this product does not at all look like the missing piece. I am not sure what you mean by this suggestion exactly.
 
Thanks again!

Comment: The 1st link shows new stoppers  with new levers. I'm suggesting it would be easier to replace the old lever with new as it is hard finding part replacements.

Comment: I repaired the 2nd link (I think).

Comment: The 3rd link is for the actual part I believe you are missing. It's for the drain stopper and linkage to the Kohler lever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! If the linkage is the bit the connects the lever in the sinkhole with the handle (I apologize for bad terminology), then I do have that in place. The lever moves up and down with the handle. The stopper itself (the bit that goes on the lever as far as I understand) is missing and does not seem to be the product you linked to, although I could be wrong...

Comment: @Roman- I added a picture in my answer that shows you the parts and how they work.

Comment: From the picture, it seems that the assembly on the left is the one I have, as I can see the tip of the "rocker arm" sticking out of the sinkhole. In this case, the part that I am missing is the part labeled as "pop-up drain stopper". Thanks a lot! I will continue my search using that keyword.